# Proving $\log(x)$ not uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to solve problem and I keep running into a different proof.

I am trying to prove $\log(x)$ not uniformly continuous (0,1) yet I keep running into the proof for uniform continuity with $\ln(x)$ on (0,1).

I am challenged and would appreciate some help. please and thank you.

Comment: How are you defining $\log(x)$? Is it $\log_{10}(x)$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Considering the sequence $\{u_n\}$ where $u_n = 10^{-n}$. The difference between two terms goes to zero, but not the difference $\ln u_{n+1} - \ln u_n$.